# Map Excel worksheet column to Bar Graph color

Tags: excel, bar-chart

If I have a chart like:

```
        x   y
        1   3
        2   8
        3   9
        4   0
color   3   1
```

is it possible to create a bar graph in Excel (2007) where there are bars for X and Y and the color index of each bar could be associated to the last row (labeled color) of the table?

Comment: I presume you mean 3 = red, 1 = black etc.? It would be possible using VBA (I think) but not sure it can be done with the out-of-the-box charting functionality in excel...

Comment: Yes that was the idea. I'm not familiar with VBA but I'll look in to it. Thanks

Comment: would you like me to provide a VBA solution or are you happy to look into that yourself? I'll leave it up to you...

Comment: @Remnant - Sorry about the late reply. I really appreciate the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This VBA snippet will plot a bar chart and use the final values in the columns as a colorindex for the bars.

To use this, simply select the two columns of data (including headers and final row) and then hit `F5` on the following code:

```
Sub BarChartWithColors()
    Dim selectedRng As Range, chartRng As Range, colorRng As Range

    Set selectedRng = Selection
    Set chartRng = Range(Selection.Cells(1, 1), Selection.Cells(selectedRng.Rows.Count - 1, 2))
    Set colorRng = Range(Selection.Cells(selectedRng.Rows.Count, 1), Selection.Cells(selectedRng.Rows.Count, 2))

    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=chartRng, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1" //Change sheet destination as appropriate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.ColorIndex = colorRng.Cells(1, 1)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Interior.ColorIndex = colorRng.Cells(1, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: I did some modifications to the range definitions and it's working now. Thanks